# How to render a series of computed bitmaps as fast as possible in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm interested in displaying a series of computed bitmaps to the screen in Silverlight as fast as possible for the purpose of animation.  Right now this is the strategy I am using which results in mid 50ies FPS on my laptop for a 1200x700 pixel image.

Can you recommend a better way?

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private int _height;
    private int _width;
    private WriteableBitmap _bitmap;
    private DateTime _start;
    private int _count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _width = (int)this.MainImage.Width;
        _height = (int)this.MainImage.Height;

        _bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(_width, _height);
        this.MainImage.Source = _bitmap;

        _start = DateTime.Now;
        RenderFrame();
    }

    private void RenderFrame()
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(RenderFrameHelp);
    }

    private void RenderFrameHelp()
    {
        int solid = -16777216;
        for (int i = 0; i < _width * _height; i++)
        {
            _bitmap.Pixels[i] = _count % 2 == 0 ? 255 : 100 | solid;
        }
        _bitmap.Invalidate();
        this.FPS.Text = (_count++ / (DateTime.Now - _start).TotalSeconds).ToString();
        RenderFrame();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

QuakeLight uses roughly the following solution:

Instead of using a WriteableBitmap, you can make a very basic PNG encoder (raw bitmap, no compression, take it from QuakeLight if you must). Fill a normal array with pixel data, encode it as PNG in memory, then wrap it in a MemoryStream and attach it to an Image. Making an uncompressed PNG basically means slapping a fixed size header in front of your array.

You could even use a producer-consumer queue so that you can build your PNG in a separate thread, letting you utilize multi-core systems for better performance.

Hope this helps. Share your experience if you try this method.

Comment: I believe the WriteableBitmap is much faster than the PNG encoder approach. The approach there is more or less the same, but you don't have to bother with the memory stream and the png header.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach will probably be to pre-render the images in your animation to a list of WriteableBitmaps and then selectively set each of them as the source of an Image control.